# Show text in DataGridView's default new row?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

If a `DataGridView` is set to allow new rows to be edited, is it possible to show a string in the its default new row, eg. "Click here to enter new item..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in design mode open `Columns` property editor (in Properties window) and for `DefaultCellStyle` of column set `NullValue = "Click here to enter new item...";`

generated code (in `InitializeComponent()` method) will look like

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 
               = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
dataGridViewCellStyle1.NullValue = "Click here to enter new item...";
this.Column1.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
```